# How do I stop my website's header from moving?

Tags: html, css, header, position

See http://www.levomedia.com/contact-us/

If your screen is of a good size there might not be a scroll so you will have to zoom in... but when there is a scroll and you move down the page, my theme forces my header to travel with you, which I would like to remove if possible.

What would be the best way of stopping this from happening, so that it stays in the same position and does not travel with you?

Comment: You should post the relevant css

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Best thing would be to remove the relevant Js code , which is causing this.

I have found this

`<script src="http://www.levomedia.com/wp-content/themes/sensitive/js/jquery.stickymenu.js?ver=3.6" type="text/javascript">`

js code file inclusion in your page, just remove it, everthing should works fine, as you intend to.

this will also improve your page rendering time and efficiency :)

Happy Coding :)

Comment: Never recommend any one to remove any js..may be this js is also used for something else always Use Hook

Comment: @MoeedFarooqui: if you can look in the js code, you will understand that , it was written only for that sticky header only

Answer (score 1):

you need to remove the css attribute :

```
position: fixed
```

Which you had used on the header.

Answer (score 1):

In your case, Js is adding the `position:fixed` attribute in topmenu once you scroll down.So you can do this by css.
convert this :

```
 <div id="topmenu" class="container" >
```

to this:

```
<div id="topmenu" class="container" style="position:relative !important" >
```

If you dont want inline Css Make a class like this:

```
.container{
position:relative !important
}
```

Comment: That seems to only work once?! I scroll down, it works, I scroll back up and down again and it follows!

Comment: Sorry, another answer suggesting simply to remove the guilty js file worked just fine and was very simple. That's all it needed. Thank you very much for your efforts and posting your suggestion though!

Comment: That is not the solution dear we should stick to the current problem otherwise it will get worst

Answer (score 1):

Stop using the jquery.stickymenu.js script and things gonna be ok. It applies position:fixed to your header, when you scroll the page down and you don't need it.

Answer (score 1):

Like this

please add `position:fixed, top:0; width:100%;` in .navbar-wrapper selector

and 
 please add `position:relative; top:66px;` in this selector .type-post, .type-post .post, .type-page, .type-page .post

**CSS**

```
   .navbar-wrapper {
    background: url("images/wild_oliva.png") repeat scroll 0 0 #EEEEEE;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    padding-bottom: 0;
    padding-top: 20px;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 1;
}
.type-post, .type-post .post, .type-page, .type-page .post {
    margin: 0 !important;
    padding: 0 !important;
    position: relative;
    top: 66px;
}
```